# Detecting `import * as name` token

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm writing some code that I want to apply only to the token from `import * as name from 'module-name'` syntax.

Is there a way to do that? I recall there is a `__ESModule` flag or something similar but that is not in the official spec, so I'm not sure if that is the right approach (and I can't find the exact article talking about it, a reference would be of great help).

i.e. this is what I want (using TypeScript in the example):

```
import * as someModule from 'module-name'
import someDefault from 'module-name'
import { someNamed } from 'module-name'
import otherImport = require('cjs-module')

let somethingElse = {} // anything
checkIsStarModule(someModule) // true
checkIsStarModule(someDefault) // false
checkIsStarModule(someNamed) // false
checkIsStarModule(otherImport) // false
checkIsStarModule(somethingElse) // false
```

And what's the proper name to describe `import * as name ...` syntax? :)

EDIT: adding some context to the question.

I'm doing something similar to `aurelia`'s `FrameworkConfiguration`.

And I want to apply it only to `someModule` as described above. This is because I don't want to accidentally execute `configure()` method on something that is not a module.

My API is `get(key: Newable<T> | T): Promise<T>` and I do allow consumers to throw in anything as `key` (`Newable<T>` is simply any class).

Thanks @estus on `__esModule`, and I realize that it is only for interop thus not useful in this context.

Comment: What purpose should this check serve? `__esModule` is the way how ES6 import can be detected.

Comment: What do you want if a module does `import * as Foo from './Foo'; export {Foo};`? Then if you `import {Foo} from './index';`, the `Foo` object would be a starred import, but not from the current file. Knowing more about the usecase you're actually trying to solve would likely help.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, that would be fine. That's actually what I expected and looking for.

Comment: Considering the context of the question, I don't see a reason why it should be forced to ES6 modules. The problem is there are no native ES6 modules (which are special in some way). Transpiled modules are plain objects. If you want to assert an argument for `configure`, it can be done by type checking, instance checking or duck-typing (`*` import isn't the best choice for the first two).

Comment: I'll second @estus' point, I think personally I'd be really annoyed to have to use an API like this.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is a stop gap I implement in TypeScript before function decorator is available. The normal use case is for class, and there is a decorator to indicate so: `@configurator() class Foo { configure() {...} }`. This is just adding support for `aurelia` style usage. I might drop it due to the extra complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing that really distinguishes [module namespace objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-module-namespace-exotic-objects) from others, anyone could create an object like that. You can test for

```
function isModuleNamespaceLike(o) {
    return o === Object(o)
    && o[Symbol.toStringTag] === "Module"
    && Object.getPrototypeOf(o) === null
    && !Object.isExtensible(o)
    && Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).every(function(p) {
        var d = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, p);
        return d.enumerable && !d.configurable;
    });
}
```

or try to look for `__esModule`, but that depends on your transpiler.

Comment: Alternatively in ES6 `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === "[object Module]"` if you don't mind `toStringTag` being overridable on misc objects.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Oh, right, how could I miss [that](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-module-namespace-objects)! I wonder whether `o[Symbol.iterator]` has the same identity on all module namespace objects…

Comment: Thanks. Like @loganfsmyth answer also. I'll be keeping it simple and see how it turns out. Thanks.